# PHP - loops through an associative array and show each group as doc1, doc 2, doc3 and text1 and text 2

Tags: php

I have a list of 2 types of documents uploaded by a user. I need to display these documents for each type as such `TypeADoc 1`, `TypeADoc 2`, `TypeADoc 3` and `TypeBDoc 1`, `TypeBDoc 2` in an html table.

Can somebody please help me. Here is what i have done so far:

```
$doc_list_terminer = clients::recupereListDocClientTerminerPourProjet($CLIENT_PROJET_ID);
$iDocs             = 0;
while ($iDocs < count($doc_list_terminer)) {
    $CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID = $doc_list_terminer[$iDocs]['CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID'];?>
    <tr>
        <td width="45%">
            <?php echo ($doc_list_terminer[$iDocs]['DOC_CLIENT_NOM']); ?>
        </td>
        <td width="45%">
            <span class="textFromDB"><a href="<?php echo $doc_list_terminer[$iDocs]['CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC']; ?>" target="_blank">
                    <?php echo basename($doc_list_terminer[$iDocs]['CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC']); ?></a> </span>
        </td>
        <?php
    if (isset($isModification) && $isModification === true) {
            ?>
            <td width="5%">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnDelDocClientProjet" onclick="delDocClientProjet(<?php echo $doc_list_terminer[$iDocs]['CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID'] ?>);"><img src="/images/delete.gif" alt="Modification" width="15" height="15"></a>
            </td>
            <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
$iDocs++;
}
```

**Sample Data:**

```
Array
(
    [901] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 701
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => seo.txt
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => Tags Manip.txt
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => test 2.txt
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
                )
        )

    [1001] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 101
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => html dom.txt
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Nom de société
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1010
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => FINTECH.txt
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Nom de société
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Please show your array data sample. it will help us to understand what's going on in code actually.

Comment: ive updated my code with the sample data

Comment: How we come to know which one `typeA` and which one `typeB?` Means to say which index of sample array will tell that this is `typeA` and other is `typeB`?

Comment: Try using `foreach ($doc_list_terminer as $key => $value) { ... }` instead

Comment: DOC_CLIENT_ID will tell that this is typeA and other is typeB

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would recommend you to try to separate logic and view (see [MVC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). There are plenty of frameworks, one of most common is [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

If you choose to have everything in the same file, try to concentrate all php code you can in a function, so your html is not full of php code.

You can start changing the `while` condition into:

```
foreach ($doc_list_terminer as $key => $value) {
    dd($key, $value)
}
```

The `dd` function (as [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)) will help you to debug your code and see the value of each variable (don't forget to remove it when you finish developing!).

=========== UPDATE ===========

In order to translate de `CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID` to its textual value, you can either create another table and use `JOIN` in order to have this text inside your associative array, or create (inside a function for example) an `ENUM` array that will do this work.

You can also use [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement for taht.

Comment: Can you please explain what is exactly your problem?

Comment: i have an associative array $doc_list_terminer in which i store a list of documents. In it there's DOC_CLIENT_ID to tell us about the type of documents it is ex. typeA,  typeB etc i need to list each documents under its type..thats all.

The sample data return by the $doc_list_terminer is in the code above. would like to list it here..but there's a limit

Comment: Guyaloni - actualy everything we need is inside $doc_list_terminer. As you can see above in the sample result: [901] and [1001] id the category id. The name of the category is [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] and the files under the category is [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC]

Comment: I am confused... so what is the problem?? I thought that your problem was how to transtale the id (e.g. `1001`) to a text (e.g. `TypeADoc 1`), isn't it?

Comment: i just got started with php, i have been trying since friday to list it in this order Type [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] and under it all the file name CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC under this Type...see my code above ...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So your issue is ordering the array?

Comment: Ok. First, please edit the subject and the description of your problem.
In order to order your data, the best place to do it is the sql query (assuming that you retrieve your data from there).

Comment: Another possibility (more complicated and less efficient) is to sort in your php code. You can use [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function to order your array with a callback that compares your data as you wish.

Comment: Thank  you all for your assistance.

Comment: Welcome! :-)
You are welcome to score answer/comments which you find helpful.. ;-)